# volume between two surfaces

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, volume, surfaces

In my textbook they solve this problem like this, Find volume between two surfaces $\quad$  $x^2+y^2-1\leq z \leq 2+\frac{2}{3}(x^2+y^2), \ \ z\geq0$

They have called the first region $D_1=x^2+y^2-1=0$, and second region $D_2=x^2+y^2=9$ and then they solve this problem with two integral
$$\iint _{D_1}   \left(2+\frac{2}{3}(x^2+y^2)-0\right) dxdy + \iint_{D_2} \left(2+\frac{2}{3}(x^2+y^2) -(x^2+y^2-1)\right)dxdy$$

My question is that why they counted the first integral? and why they divided the region into two parts?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see a $2D$ sketch of the region (projection on $XZ$ or $YZ$ plane) and what each integral is finding.

What you see shaded on the left is what the first integral is finding. What you see shaded on the right is what the second integral is finding.

[image]

Since it needs to find the volume between solids above $XY$ plane ($z \geq 0$), it should have set up the first integral for $x^2 + y^2 - 1$ instead of for $(2 + \frac {2}{3}(x^2+y^2))$ to remove the volume below $XY$ plane.

[image]

So the correct integral would be -

$\displaystyle \iint _{D_1} (x^2 + y^2 - 1) \, dx \, dy + \iint_{D_2} \left(2+\frac{2}{3}(x^2+y^2) -(x^2+y^2-1)\right) \, dx \, dy$

$\displaystyle \int_{-1}^{1} \int_{-\sqrt{1-y^2}}^{\sqrt{1-y^2}} (x^2 + y^2 - 1) \, dx \, dy = -\frac{\pi}{2}$

$\displaystyle \int_{-3}^{3} \int_{-\sqrt{9-y^2}}^{\sqrt{9-y^2}} \left(2+\frac{2}{3}(x^2+y^2) -(x^2+y^2-1)\right) \, dx \, dy = \frac{27 \pi}{2}$

Adding them gives you $13 \pi$ as the volume of the desired region.

EDIT:

As per the integral setup you sent, this is what the textbook is doing.

[image]

Comment: @ Math Lover 
If the other integral does as you drew why not just use this instead. Because we want to find the volume between the surfaces and other integrals just doing this. right? I do not know i'm just asking. The answer in my texbook is correct 
but I have a hard time understanding the reasoning. 
Do you know why they used the first integral?

Comment: I have double checked this, in my textbook they have written as I wrote and also got the same answer as you $(13\pi)$.  Your answer seems reasonable but I do not understand why in my textbook they have done so and got the same answer as you. So weird, maybe the volume that they counted twice take each other out?

Comment: this is what they have written$$2\pi \int_{0}^{1} \left(2+\frac{2}{3}r^2\right)rdr+ 2\pi \int_{1}^{3}\left(3-\frac{1}{3}r^2\right)rdr=13\pi$$

Comment: Now this is a different integral than what it appeared first in the question. This will give $13 \pi$. The first integral is exactly what is in my diagram. The second integral is different. It is not for the whole domain but just starting at $r = 1$. Do you want me to draw and show how that will look?

Comment: thank you so much now i understand this

Comment: You are welcome!

Answer (score 0):

Projection on $Oxy$ of intersection of paraboloids  $z=x^2+y^2-1$ and $z= 2+\frac{2}{3}(x^2+y^2)$  is $x^2+y^2=9$, so first integral is volume of cylinder with projection $x^2+y^2=1$ and "roof" $z= 2+\frac{2}{3}(x^2+y^2)$. Second integral is difference between two paraboloids, but, they should take it over $D_2 \setminus D_1$.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

$$\int\limits_{r=0}^3 2 \pi r (( 2 + 2 r^2/3) - \max[0,(r^2 - 1)])\ dr = 13 \pi$$